# Value doesn't change on database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Hello everyone i am facing a problem and i hope you can help me..
So i am saving my user data in a User collection.

```
This is my User schema.....
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    googleId: String,
    facebookId: String,
    twitterId: String,
    name: String,
    userImg: String,
    cart: [{
      type: Object
    }],
    booking: [{
      type: Object
    }]
  });
```

Now i am adding a food item from my menu to the cart array which is in the user schema and it works fine but i started facing problem when i want to update the quantity of the food item from my cart page.. I have given two button **+** for increment the quantity and **-** for decrement the quantity..
Also i have given a **remove** button to remove that particular food item from cart.

```
code for the Increment, Decrement and Remove the food Item(from cart page)

<a href="/cartUpdate/<%=product.title %>?action=subtract">
  <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" name="button">-</button>
</a>

<a href="/cartUpdate/<%=product.title %>?action=add">
  <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" name="button">+</button>
</a>

<a href="/cartUpdate/<%=product.title %>?action=clear">
  <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" name="button">Remove</button>
</a>
```

Now my problem is that it doesn't update the value of quantity in database but the remove button works completely fine i don't know why

```
// Update cart code
router.get("/cartUpdate/:product",isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
  var productName = req.params.product;
  var userId = req.user.id;
  var action = req.query.action;

  User.findById(userId, (err,result)=>{
    var cart = result.cart;
    for (var i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
      if (cart[i].title === productName) {
        switch (action) {
          case "add":
            console.log(cart[i].qty);     
            cart[i].qty++;
            console.log(cart[i].qty);
            console.log(cart);
            break;
          case "subtract":
            cart[i].qty--;
          case "clear":
            cart.splice(i, 1);
            break;
          default:
            console.log("update problem");
            break;
        }
        break;
      }
    }
    result.save(err=>{
      if(!err){
        req.flash('success', "cart updated");
        res.redirect("/cart");
      }
    });
    console.log(result.cart);
  })

});
```

Now if anyone can help me out... How should i update and save the quantity in database?

Answer (score 0):

You're not updating the database after making the local update on the variable `cart`. Once you update the local variable make sure you update the database too